# C# preventing entries so you don't get "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

Tags: c#

I have a situation where I am reading a bill of material file.
I only care about the first two strings in each line then I want to move on to the next line.  Of course I am skipping the first 3 lines intentionally, just header crap.

```
    foreach (string line in lines.Skip(3))
    {
        string[] entries = line.Split(null);

        creoBOM newCreoBOM = new creoBOM();

        newCreoBOM.identCode = entries[0];
        newCreoBOM.itemQty = entries[1];

        creoBOMA.Add(newCreoBOM);

        messageWindow.Text += entries[0] + " " + entries[1];
        messageWindow.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }


    messageWindow.Text += "creoBOMFile Loaded";
    messageWindow.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

If the file only has two variables for each line that is fine.
If the file has let's say many entries past [0] and [1] it gives me an out of bounds error.

What is the best way to handle this situation?  I am currently splitting using the null char because ITEM1 AND QTY1 are always separated by a space, guaranteed. It is system generated by another piece of software.  I am sure there is an easy way to basically go to a new line after entries[1] is read.  entries[2+..n] should not exist because I can't guarantee how many entries truly exist on each line.

Example file that is good when reading in the file:

```
ITEM1 QTY1

ITEM2 QTY2

ITEM3 QTY3
```

Example file that is bad when reading in the file:

```
ITEM1 QTY1 DESCRIPTION1 RANDOMJIBBERISH1

ITEM2 QTY2 RANDOMJIbberish2 DESCRIPTION2 SOMENEWVAR

ITEM3 QTY3
```

Comment: Which line causes the problem

Comment: newCreoBOM.itemQty = entries[1];

Comment: I think you are reading the last line, which is blank and thus not splitting into more than 1 element, and [1] is actually not there.

Comment: Why are you splitting on null and not on space?

Comment: Ah this makes sense.  I need to program in to skip blank lines then.  I will look this up.  Eventually I have to also get it to stop reading at a key word but I will tackle that after I fix this issue.  C# is very new to me so I am playing around with it.

Comment: I heard splitting on null is safer?  No idea, I am open for suggestions though. :)  I can easily switch it back to a space if need be.

Comment: From the documentation `If the separator argument is null or contains no characters, the method treats white-space characters as the delimiters` there is no safer

Comment: Learn to use the debugger- it is a very valuable tool! in this case, you would have seen that there is only 1 value in the "entries" array - which is the line with no spaces/whatever you split on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.IndexOutOfRangeException` in your program comes from the empty lines, not from the extra data.

Here's my attempt:

```
foreach (var filePath in new[] { "file1.txt", "file2.txt" })
foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
{
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
        {
            continue;//Skip empty lines
        }
        string[] entries = line.Split(null);

        if (entries.Length < 2)
        {
            throw new Exception("Ivalid line");
        }

        if (entries.Length > 2)
        {
            throw new Exception("Suspicious line");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(entries[0] + " " + entries[1]);

        //TODO This code doesn't properly handle files where the first column has spaces
    } catch (Exception )
    {
        //It's may best to catch exceptions per line so that one bad line doesn't break the whole import
        //HOWEVER, it may be a good idea to break *the whole* import 
        //if even one line is bad 
        //so that we don't miss data. 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use continue to avoid crash:

```
string[] entries = line.Split(null);
if (entries.Length<2)
   continue;
```